# write a http post request to bot framework running on localhost

Tags: c#, botframework

I have a bot running on http://localhost:3978/api/messages.
Instead of debugging it using an emulator, can I go about using a http post request to the messaging endpoint of the bot?
If so, how do I go about doing it?

I am using c# microsoft bot framework, and I am new to this application.
I do not want to use any channels or DirectLine api, just using Httpclient.

Comment: Not sure I understand, but cant you just use your web browser?

Comment: i want to create a console application using httpclient to call the endpoint. Not sure if I understand your question on using web browser

Comment: @torsan the API is waiting for HTTP POST request, not GET

Comment: What I believe that Bot woks in two-way communication. So both Client and Server opens a port to communicate. When a request is sent by client then it directs to server that where the server should sends the callback message. What you are requesting here, is also require to open two way channels if you are interested to receive the response back from server.

Comment: @Hane, Communication with bot framework in not as simple as directly calling a REST API. When a message is triggered via some channel, bot records some identification of that channel and user, and converts the message from channel to a channel agnostic format, which the bot's code receive. That channel & user, is also used for sending proactive message. Think about it, if you just an HTTP client, to whom does the bot send the message when you are not available. You can create a console app to interact with bot using Directline API. Directline API available in .NET & NodeJS and in swagger form.

Comment: As an alternative to using the C# or Node.js client libraries, you can generate your own client library in the language of your choice by using the Direct Line API 3.0 Swagger file. https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/restapi/directline3/swagger.json

You can use swagger-codegen to create APIs in your favorite language.

Comment: @MasterChief, My initial plan was to use the directline api to call my bot, the problem is that microsoft put the bot registration channel from the developer's portal into azure, which forces me to use a subscription plan. The free subscription plan that I am using has expired and I am not able to create the bot registration channel due to this fact. Hence, using directline api is out of the question.

Comment: @Hane, in that case, I think, a better question would be, can a bot developed using MS botframework deployed without using Azure portal? Which is an interesting question in itself, and will look forward to the answer.

Comment: Also, as per my experience, if there is not much traffic to your bot's web service (likely during development stage), it doesn't cost anything. I am using a bot for our organization internal purpose, and it costs 0$/month. You should look at some of the benefits of azure free account. https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free/free-account-faq/

10 web, mobile, or API apps with Azure App Service with 1 GB storage - *Always free*

Answer (score 2):

You can do this with C# using code similar to below.  Note that you would have to construct an `Activity` to send by setting the appropriate properties for your needs, which is not included in this code.

```
//make a call to get an auth token
string token;
using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    var values = new NameValueCollection();
    values["grant_type"] = "client_credentials";
    values["client_id"] = "YOUR APP ID";
    values["client_secret"] = "NcOXRwb51joibEfzUuNE04u";
    values["scope"] = "YOUR APP ID/.default";

    var response =
        client.UploadValues("https://login.microsoftonline.com/botframework.com/oauth2/v2.0/token", values);

    var responseString = Encoding.Default.GetString(response);
    var result = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<ResponseObject>(responseString);
    token = result.access_token;
}

//you will need to adjust this value for your project.
//this example for a proxy project so the service url here is
//just an arbitrary endpoint I was using to send activities to
activity.ServiceUrl = "http://localhost:4643/api/return";    

var jsonActivityAltered = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(activity);

using (var client = new WebClient())
{
    client.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/json");
    client.Headers.Add("Authorization", $"Bearer {token}");

    try
    {
        var btmResponse = client.UploadString("http://localhost:3971/api/messages", jsonActivityAltered);
    }
    catch (Exception e)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(e);
        throw;
    }
}
```

Comment: if the client id and client secret is from the bot builder sdk, if the sdk is not published on the server where they generate a random id and secret for you, can I just populate the fields myself in the bot builder sdk and pass the same thing over to the values that you stated at the top?

Answer (score -1):

Have you tried using something like postman? (it's free and easy to use)

https://www.getpostman.com/

You can also write scripts in postman

otherwise you can just go to the endpoint of your API in the browser

http://localhost:3978/api/

I see you mentioned you wanted to make a console application.

You could do that. I'd suggest using postman though.

Here is an example of sending a file as well as some querystring data and Authentication using a Bearer token.

Sorry it may not be exact. Had to do a bit of copy pasting/deleting from some code examples if have

```
        using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
        {
            JObject jsonModel = new JObject();
            client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:3978/");
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Clear();
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(new MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));
            client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Bearer", AuthToken);

                using (var multipartFormDataContent = new MultipartFormDataContent())
                {
                    var values = new[]
                    {
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("firstname", lastname),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("lastname", lastname),
                        new KeyValuePair<string, string>("payloadFile", FileName)
                    };

                    foreach (var keyValuePair in values)
                    {
                        multipartFormDataContent.Add(new StringContent(keyValuePair.Value),
                        String.Format("\"{0}\"", keyValuePair.Key));
                    }

                    ByteArrayContent fileContent = new ByteArrayContent(File.ReadAllBytes(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/output/" + FileName)));
                    string FullxmlString = File.ReadAllText(Path.Combine(HttpContext.Current.Server.MapPath("~/uploads/output/" + FileName)));


                    fileContent.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("payloadFile") { FileName = "payloadFile" };
                    multipartFormDataContent.Add(fileContent);

                    HttpResponseMessage response = client.PostAsync("api/message", multipartFormDataContent).Result;
                    string returnString = response.Content.ToString();

                    using (HttpContent content = response.Content)
                    {
                        string res = "";
                        Task<string> result = content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                        res = result.Result;
                    }
                }
       }
```

Comment: The Authentication is missing on your sample, could you add it?

Comment: Updated, see if that helps

Comment: If i remove [botauthentication] from the messagescontroller.cs, do i need to put in the authentication header in my httpclient?

Comment: I've never used bot authentication to be honest. I thought the authentication you were referring to was a bearer token authentication, which is pretty standard for a webAPI

Comment: This sample is not really relevant for simple bot request